# Replacing mounting brackets on dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

After moving in to an older house, the dishwasher started coming undone from the mounting brackets and tipping forward. I opened it up and saw that the mounting brackets had completely cleaved apart. I believe that the brackets are brazed(?) to the frame of the dishwasher itself (picture below), is it possible to replace such brackets?

[image: picture of broken bracket]

The dishwasher is a Frigidaire that is 20+ years old, model number FDB989GFC2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like spot-weld rather than hrazing, originally....

Comment: Yes and no- it looks like a spot weld to me too. It is possible to replace the brackets (and spot weld) but to do so would be a semi-industrial chore. No doubt there's a solution, but I think that you need someone to be there to assess the situation and options. For what it's worth making a new braket and mounting it on top of the old one with bolts might be an option, but again, you really need ground support.

Comment: [Here](http://c.searspartsdirect.com/lis_png/PLDM/P0207094-00003.png) is a picture of the frame; would you show where on the frame your break is, and clarify just what's tipping forward?

Comment: The frame is intact, the mounting brackets that attach the frame to the cabinet are completely separated near the base of the bracket, just above the weld as visible in the picture. The brackets themselves are attached on the top of the frame, the same part where the screws labeled 4 go in, about 3 or 4 inches in from the outer edge of the frame. The entire dishwasher is tipping out from the cabinet when the door is open and a drawer is pulled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

looks like the legs are connected by a runner.  I'd stabilize the dishwasher by attach the runners to floor using a right-angle drill to reach as far back as comfortable, say 8" or more.

http://www.harborfreight.com/38-in-variable-speed-reversible-close-quarters-drill-60610.html